# Windows or Android software to measure internet latency

Tags: windows, gratis, android, networking, diagnostics

I'm looking for a gratis piece of Windows and/or Android software that will ping a list pre-defined (or configurable) sites in order to determine average latency.

By repeating the process numerous times, and taking the median of the averages, I'm hoping to determine a reasonable average latency value.  I can do that part by hand, if the software cannot.

The software can by CLI (command line interface) or GUI (graphical user interface).

Answer (score 1):

#### How can I ping a list of sites in order to determine average latency?

On Windows you can use [PingInfoView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multiple_ping_tool.html) (free) by [Nirsoft](https://www.nirsoft.net/):

> PingInfoView is a small utility that allows you to easily ping
>   multiple host names and IP addresses, and watch the result in one
>   table.
>
> It automatically ping to all hosts every number of seconds that you
>   specify, and displays the number of succeed and failed pings, as well
>   as the average ping time.
>
> You can also save the ping result into text/html/xml file, or copy it
>   to the clipboard.

It even works out the average ping time (latency) for you (per site).

Example output:

[image]

[image]

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [Nirsoft](https://www.nirsoft.net/) in any way, I am just an end user of their software.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `PowerShell` using the [.NET System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
$PingObj = New-Object System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
$PingObj.Send("www.somewebsite.local")

Status        : Success
Address       : 1.1.1.1
RoundtripTime : 70
Options       : System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingOptions
Buffer        : {97, 98, 99, 100...}
```